# SharePoint List with large number of columns goes off the screen in Oslo Theme

Tags: list, column, design

My SharePoint site uses Oslo theme. I have a SharePoint List with large number of columns.

Whenever this List is opened, there is alot of blank space on the left side of the page.

Here's screenshot-

[image]

How should I overcome this issue?

Comment: it will happen in any theme

Comment: Seattle works perfectly but I can't use it.

Comment: remove unwanted columns from view

Comment: Of course that will solve the problem but displaying this much columns is the requirement. So, can't do that either.